# Getting data correctly from SPAN ID beatifulsoup

Tags: python

I need to bring a specific value of the page and it does not bring it to me.

Here is my code :

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

url="http://www.mae.com.ar/old.aspx?p=mercados/Forex/Default.aspx"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
target = soup.find("span", id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GVPREREFBCRA_ctl02_Label20")
print (target)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the URL as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://www.mae.com.ar/mercados/Forex/Default.aspx')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
quote = soup.select_one('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GVPREREFBCRA_ctl02_Label20').text
```